# How to retrieve current user data from firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried this way, but i'm getting an error.

The error:

> The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'CollectionReference'. (undefined_method at [myapp] android\app\lib\useracc.dart:32)

```
void getData() async{
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        var vari =FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

        setState (() {
          name = vari.data()['firstname'];
        }
        );

  }
```

**Signup/Register Page**

```
Future<User?> _register(String fname,String lname ,String email, String password) async{
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    try {
      UserCredential userCrendetial =  await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);

      print("Account created Succesfull");

      userCrendetial.user!.updateDisplayName(fname);
      userCrendetial.user!.updateDisplayName(lname);

      await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).set({
        "firstname": fname,
        "lastname" : lname,
        "email": email,
        "uid": _auth.currentUser!.uid,
      });

      return userCrendetial.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

This is the user account from where i want to fetch info:
[image]

Please help. I'm struck here a long time.

Answer (score 1):

if you've saved your user's details in firestore and its document id is the same as that of user ID (which is preferred for ease of access and control), then:

```
var vari =FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.uid).get();
```

This gets the document of the user, and the type is DocumentSnapshot.

`Map<String,dynamic> userData = vari as Map<String,dynamic>;`

now userData is stored in form of Map. suppose you want to access their 'name', so the syntax now goes like `userData['name']`.

Similarly other fields can be accessed from variable. It's preferred to store userData in a Provider to access it's contents anywhere in your app.

[image: Heres a sample database structure]

Full code snippet

```
void getData() async{
    User? user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
        var vari =FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user!.uid).get();
Map<String,dynamic> userData = vari as Map<String,dynamic>;

        setState (() {
          name = userData['firstname']; //or name = userData['name']
        }
        );

  }
```

Comment: I'm new to Flutter. I will post the code from my register page.

Comment: sure, ill try to help you out

Comment: @QueenBee yes, my code should work, give it a try.

Comment: Did it work? It'd be great if you could accept the answer if it did.

Comment: It's not showing any result. My screen is white as a sheet.

Comment: could you add the errors raised while execution

Comment: Ive updated the code: `.doc(user!.uid).get()`

Comment: It didn't work out, but thanks anyway!

Comment: There is no error shown in the log files.

Comment: are you calling getData()? call it after some time of wiget build

Comment: How to call it? The function returns void.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245362/discussion-between-delwinn-and-queenbee).

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the `currentUser` document then access its data:

```
void getData() async{
    var vari = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .get();

    setState (() {
      name = vari.data()['firstname'];
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey, my page is blank, it is not showing anything, not even an error.